# How to set a custom font weight?

Tags: android, fonts

like the subject implies, I would like to programmatically change/set a [font weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font#Weight) for an arbitrary font.

Edit: I mean on a font for drawing strings in general.

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't modify that once you load the font. You can create a new Typeface from your existing typeface, like so:

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myfontfamily.otf");
Typeface boldTypeface = Typeface.create(typeface, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Of course, that also depends on whether or not your specific font HAS different weights. Typically (always?) these will be separate files anyway, for example, Bitstream Vera Sans has Vera.ttf, VeraBd.ttf, VeraIt.ttf, VeraBI.ttf, one each for each different posture/weight combination. Just load the proper Typeface depending on which weight you need.

EDIT: Yeah, fonts are usually redrawn very specifically for different weights, at least for well-designed fonts. If you're just looking for something like a faux bold style (like Photoshop or Office do for fonts without a defined bold style), you might be able to use the [`TextPaint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html) class, and set the `FAKE_BOLD_TEXT_FLAG` flag to get a similar result. Alternately, you could play around with different stroke widths to get some similar effects. Keep it limited to very small modifications though, especially at small sizes, or you may end up with the text being intersected by the stroke, and just plain look ugly. :)

I'd recommend just playing with the fake bold flag and see how that goes, if that's what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Updated my answer, might help you some, not sure.

Comment: Well, I tried that but it seems that only option is to use a custom font family. Anyway, thanks for an answer.